# C++11 concurrency; condition_variable; fizz, buzz, fizzbuzz; STUCK

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, condition-variable, fizzbuzz

I am unable to find any bug, the program doesn't show any output; however if I introduce a cout with some print in number() just after while I see some output, are signals getting missed?

I have launched 4 threads, all are using unique_lock on a common mutex and a condition variable. The same logic works if I use semaphores but when I converted them to c++11 condition_variable I am seeing no output on the screen. The threads are hung and are waiting for signals. But the thread[3] should run because the condition for which it is on wait if true; curr=1.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>  
using namespace std; 

class FizzBuzz {
private:
    int n;
    int curr;
    std::mutex mtx; 
    std::condition_variable cv;

public:
    FizzBuzz(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        curr = 1;
    }

    // printFizz() outputs "fizz".
      void fizz(function<void()> printFizz) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (curr <= n && curr % 3 == 0 && curr % 5 != 0);});
            printFizz();
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }

    // printBuzz() outputs "buzz".
      void buzz(function<void()> printBuzz) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (curr <= n && curr % 3 != 0 && curr % 5 == 0);});
            printBuzz();
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }

    // printFizzBuzz() outputs "fizzbuzz".
      void fizzbuzz(function<void()> printFizzBuzz) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (curr <= n && curr % 3 == 0 && curr % 5 == 0);});
            printFizzBuzz();
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }

    // printNumber(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
      void number(function<void(int)> printNumber) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (curr <= n && curr % 3 != 0 && curr % 5 != 0);});
            printNumber(curr);
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }
};
void printFizz (void) {
  cout << "Fizz";
};
void printBuzz (void) {
  cout << "Buzz";
};
void printFizzBuzz (void) {
  cout << "FizzBuzz";
};
void printNumber (int n) {
  cout << n;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int num;

  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num);

  std::function<void(void)> f_fizz     = printFizz;
  std::function<void(void)> f_buzz     = printBuzz;
  std::function<void(void)> f_fizzbuzz = printFizzBuzz;
  std::function<void(int)>  f_num      = printNumber;
  FizzBuzz *objPtr = new FizzBuzz(num);

  std::thread threads[4];


  threads[0] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::fizz, objPtr ,f_fizz);
  threads[1] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::buzz,objPtr, f_buzz);
  threads[2] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::fizzbuzz,objPtr, f_fizzbuzz);
  threads[3] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::number,objPtr, f_num);

  for (auto& th: threads) th.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notify_all` reaches other threads, but the condition `curr <=n && ...`is not satisfied. Therefore, the other threads continue to wait and hang the program.

For example, the following code would terminate properly, because setting the terminated flag will wake all threads and have them break the loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>  
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std; 

class FizzBuzz {
private:
    int n;
    int curr;
    std::mutex mtx; 
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool terminated;

public:
    FizzBuzz(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        curr = 1;
        terminated = false;
    }

    // printFizz() outputs "fizz".
      void fizz(function<void()> printFizz) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (terminated || (curr % 3 == 0 && curr % 5 != 0));});
            if (terminated)
                break;
            printFizz();
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
        cout << "fizz exiting" << endl;
        terminated = true;
    }

    // printBuzz() outputs "buzz".
      void buzz(function<void()> printBuzz) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (terminated || (curr % 3 != 0 && curr % 5 == 0));});
            if (terminated)
                break;
            printBuzz();
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
        cout << "buzz exiting" << endl;
        terminated = true;
    }

    // printFizzBuzz() outputs "fizzbuzz".
      void fizzbuzz(function<void()> printFizzBuzz) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (terminated || (curr % 3 == 0 && curr % 5 == 0));});
            if (terminated)
                break;
            printFizzBuzz();
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
        cout << "fizzbuzz exiting" << endl;
        terminated = true;
    }

    // printNumber(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
      void number(function<void(int)> printNumber) {
        while(curr <= n) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (terminated || (curr % 3 != 0 && curr % 5 != 0));});
            if (terminated)
                break;
            printNumber(curr);
            curr++;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_all();
        }
        cout << "number exiting" << endl;
        terminated = true;
    }
};
void printFizz (void) {
  cout << "Fizz" << endl;
};
void printBuzz (void) {
  cout << "Buzz" << endl;
};
void printFizzBuzz (void) {
  cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
};
void printNumber (int n) {
  cout << n << endl;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int num;

  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num);

  std::function<void(void)> f_fizz     = printFizz;
  std::function<void(void)> f_buzz     = printBuzz;
  std::function<void(void)> f_fizzbuzz = printFizzBuzz;
  std::function<void(int)>  f_num      = printNumber;
  FizzBuzz *objPtr = new FizzBuzz(num);

  std::thread threads[4];


  threads[0] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::fizz, objPtr ,f_fizz);
  threads[1] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::buzz,objPtr, f_buzz);
  threads[2] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::fizzbuzz,objPtr, f_fizzbuzz);
  threads[3] = std::thread(&FizzBuzz::number,objPtr, f_num);

  for (auto& th: threads) {
      th.join();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am unable to understand why on cv.notify_all() the condition "curr <=n &&" is not satisfied? curr starts from 1 and is indeed 1 <= n; so shouldn't it be satisfied for all waiting threads?? And the Predicate for other waiting threads becomes True depending on entire condition and they come out. I am puzzled why even first number "1, 2, fizz, 4, buzz..." from this series isn't printed. I am first time experimenting with condition_variable so little confused. The semaphore version this code words perfectly!

Comment: @abhins In your implementation, the last printing thrad will increment `curr` and `notify_all`. Therefore all other threads will evaluate `curr <= n` as `false` and continue waiting. If you are satified with the answer, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I realized this now after putting it to gdb. The value of curr was 21 and still the thread were waiting. There was no condition for them to come out..modified like this..cv.wait(lck, [&]{return (curr > n || (curr % 3 == 0 && curr % 5 != 0));});
            if (curr > n)
              break;

Comment: that begs another question. If the curr has indeed reached 21 why did the cout not show the output of the numbers thus far printed? What can be done to flush the output? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @abhins Your did not use `cout << "string" << endl`. Therefore, cout will buffer the output until it sees a nextline character. The other choice is to use `flush` rather than `\n`